# How to bind total records from json in Jqgrid toolbar

Tags: jquery, json, jqgrid

I am using jQuery Ajax to call Webservice to display data (JSON format) in jqgrid. This is what my json format looks like,

```
{
    "records": "4",
    "response": [
        {
            "id": 141505,
            "docno": "4032407",
            "Checked": "No",
            "vendorid": "40238"
        },
        {
            "id": 141506,
            "docno": "4032405",
            "Checked": "No",
            "vendorid": "40286"
        },
        {
            "id": 141507,
            "docno": "4032409",
            "Checked": "No",
            "vendorid": "40282"
        },
        {
            "id": 141508,
            "docno": "4032419",
            "Checked": "No",
            "vendorid": "40282"
        }
    ]
}
```

and this is my jsonreader,

```
jsonReader: {
          repeatitems: false,
          id: "id",
          root: function (obj) { return obj; },
          page: function (obj) { return obj.length > 0 ? 1 : 0; },
          total: function () { return 1; },
          records: function (obj) { return obj.length; },
          subgrid: {
          repeatitems: false,
          id: "id",
          root: function (obj) { return obj; }
          }
        },
```

data is binding in jqgrid correctly, but not total records (which shown in json)... how to bind that total records in JQGrid bottom of the toolbar.
i.e (View 1 - 4 of 4)

Comment: what is displayed now on place of "View 1 - 4 of 4"? Do you use `loadonce: true`? Which `datatype` you use?

Comment: Sorry for the delay. I have 40 Records in my Jqgrid and I have set only 30 records to be display in 1st page and next 30 records in 2nd page and so on, but my Jqgrid displays only 30 records in place of "View 1 - 30 of 30" with Pagination displays "Page 1 of 1".